# How to add a password to join LAN network

Tags: windows, passwords, lan, ethernet

I have a router set up with wireless passwords, but anybody who plugs an ethernet cable into a wallsocket will have access to the network regardless of passwords. Is there a program or method of forcing users to type in a password or something similar to join the network through an ethernet socket?

Comment: It all depends on your definition of "joining the LAN", do you want them not to be able to access the internet, not be able to connect to shares on computers on the network, or not be able to even passively sniff traffic on the network? (the last one is hard to do and will cost expensive hardware)

Comment: @Anton8000 Look for the 802.11x security protocol.  It supports both WLAN and ethernet authentication.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X

Comment: The low-tech solution would be to put the router in locked box.  You'd want to have it made out of something that wouldn't block the signal, like wood.  Depending on your security requirements, it wouldn't have to be unbreakable, but just provide enough protection to deter people, and provide evidence if it had been broken into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are some methods to force authentication.

1. Use 801.x on Cisco Switch (Expensive and need knowledge)
2. Run VPN server on router or another machine, and just allow users connected to your VPN (All protocol will pass through VPN)
3. Run proxy on your router or another machine, and just allow users connected to your proxy (Depending on proxy type,some protocol cannot pass through it. So this solution make restriction for users)
4. Use MAC filtering on your router

I suggest second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but this generally requires more expensive switches, called *managed switches*. These let you enable, disable, and authorize computers on a per-port basis. These easily cost $100+ currently, mostly due to the limited environments in which they are needed (typically, corporate/enterprise networks).

Comment: The specific term you need to check if the managed switch supports is a [Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) for its Ethernet ports.